# Fullcalendar view display goToDate breaks prev, next and today

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In my `viewDisplay` method i have a `goToDate` method that actually when you click on a day, week or month the calender view go to this specific clicked day with what ever you choose from day. week or month

```
 viewDisplay: function (view) {
   var current_clicked_day = $(window).data('cell_date') || new Date();
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', current_clicked_day);
  },
```

and This is working fine, However it breaks all events related to prev, next and today

<kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Today</kbd>

i'm not sure if this is something in my code or a bug in the library

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4bg2B/)

**For Example**

if you click on a day -on the calendar - and then click on <kbd>Day</kbd> in the upper right corner and then <kbd>Today</kbd> that wouldn't work, plus i don't get any errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am understanding, you would like to display the `agendaDay` view when you click on a day in the `month` or `weekAgenda` views (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)

First of all, `viewDisplay` has been deprecated (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/removed/viewDisplay/) a couple of builds ago. I suggest you update your library.

To achieve what you want you need to call `dayClick` (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/)

Here is a working fiddle based on yours.
I have commented `viewDisplay` and added the `dayClick` part just after. http://jsfiddle.net/4bg2B/3/

Comment: Not only the agendaDay it could be week or the month too, what i was trying to do is when you click on a day then you can click on either day, week or month view and it will display the week for example within the week range... i think the event i'm looking for is viewRender since you mentioned that viewDisplay is deprecated .. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to remove the line $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay'); in the dayClick event? You can also remove the if condition around.
When the month view is displayed, I click on the 26 of June, if I choose then the day view (top right corner), I end up on the 26 of June, if I chose the week view, I end up on the week from the 22 to 28. In that same week, if I click on the day 24, and then on the day view (top right corner), the 24 of june day view is displayed.
Is that the behaviour you try to achieve?

Comment: yes but then when you click on today or prev or next this wouldn't work

Comment: For a reason I ignore, it comes from the gotoDate function in viewRender. If you comment that line (or the whole event for that matter), it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/4bg2B/5/